# Firestore Friendlist does not show the right way

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently trying to make a friendlist with Firestore. My coding is owrking but not the right way. 
So I am have a friendlist in my database which looks like this: [Databse pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2i6G.png)

So Document is saved under my ID which saves otherIDs from users, who accepted a friend request.

So right now it looks like this in the app: [new database picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fulbg.png)

It shows me that i have 3 friends, which is correct and when i click on one of the profiles it shows me my friend the rght way.

This is how it should look: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3afT.png)

My important code lokks like this right now:

```
   mFirestore.collection("users").document(usid).collection("friends").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            if (e != null) {

            }
            for(DocumentChange doc : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){

                    String user_id = doc.getDocument().getId();
                    //Toast.makeText(yourFriends.this, fAuth.getUid(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println(user_id);
                    System.out.println(fAuth.getUid());
                    if (fAuth.getUid().equals(user_id)){

                        Map map = doc.getDocument().getData();
                        System.out.println(map.size());
                        //Toast.makeText(yourFriends.this, map.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        for(Object friendid : map.values()){

                            friendid.toString();


                            Users users = doc.getDocument().toObject(Users.class).withId((String)friendid);
                            //Toast.makeText(yourFriends.this, (String)friendid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            usersList.add(users);
                        }
                    }
                    usersListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

So I am getting my friendlist but it does not load the information in my userlist.

Answer (score 0):

Your Database structure is wrong. You have to start one more collection under a user and within that you need to store the documnet and under that store the friends data. After this get that collection to the Listview or Recyclerview It will come.

Comment: It did it. I added a picture to my post.

Comment: Check My Post .. How to create a DB structure. It should be like a tree.